Valores atipicos de una muestra Python
estoy trabajando en una funcion sencilla que recibe una muestra calcula la puntucaion tipica y retorna los valores atipicos.
Sinceramente comence a tener dudas si estoy haciendo bien el procedimiento, les comparto mi funcion.
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1000]
def valoresAtipicos(muestra):
    media = sum(muestra) // len(muestra)
    desviacionTipica = (sum(muestra) // len(muestra)) ** 0.5
    puntuacionTipica = []
    for i in muestra:
        puntuacion = (i - media) / desviacionTipica
        if puntuacion > 3 or puntuacion < -3:
            puntuacionTipica.append(i)

    return puntuacionTipica


No sé cómo es el cálculo de eso. Pero si necesitas obtener la raíz cuadrada es mejor usar la función sqrt y list comprehension: [x for x in muestra if not -3 < (x - media) / desviacionTipica < 3] que es más compacto y eficiente que append.

Escogiste un mal set de datos. Tiene media 95 y desv. típica 9.7. Eso hace todos los elementos atípicos. Prueba reemplazando el 1000 por 100 en la lista numeros

Segun revise el resultado para esa muestra es: [1000], por eso me quede confundido.

Aldo, aparte de que no debes usar la división entera ( / y no // ), la desviación tipica no es la raiz cuadrada de la media: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desviaci%C3%B3n_t%C3%ADpica Ese es el principal error, el resto del algoritmo es correcto, se puede hacer más eficiente pero es una implementación válida para obtener los valores atípicos mediante z-score, aunque hay otras formas, como el rango intercuartílico que es también ampliamente usado.

La función tiene algunos errores que afectan a la precisión del cálculo de la desviación estándar y la media:

La media debe calcularse utilizando la división flotante (/).

La desviación estándar debe calcularse utilizando la fórmula estándar.

El cálculo de la desviación estándar también debe incluir la raíz cuadrada de la varianza.

La condición para identificar valores atípicos generalmente utiliza un umbral de puntuación típica z-score de 3, pero debe aplicarse correctamente.



import math

numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1000]

def valores_atipicos(muestra):
    media = sum(muestra) / len(muestra)
    varianza = sum((x - media) ** 2 for x in muestra) / len(muestra)
    desviacion_tipica = math.sqrt(varianza)
    puntuacion_tipica = []

    for i in muestra:
        puntuacion = (i - media) / desviacion_tipica
        if puntuacion > 3 or puntuacion < -3:
            puntuacion_tipica.append(i)

    return puntuacion_tipica



Por favor, muestra los resultados de la ejecución.

Ok, lo acabo de editar en la respuesta

Hola Erick, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Me he tomado la libertad de editar un poco tu respuesta, básicamente algo de formato y corregir un error de sangrado en el código. Saludos.

Erick, usualmente las imágenes se utilizan para mostrar contenido gráfico. Hay personas que, por una variedad de razones, no tienen acceso a ver imágenes en el sitio. Sugiero que publiques el código y los resultados únicamente como texto.  Un saludo.
